# Converting a date formatted with a pipe using momentjs to a iso date or format compatible with angular2-nativeDateModule

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a date that gets returned from a C#/asp.net API.  The date gets returned in milliseconds so I use a pipe to convert the date to a human readable form.  I am trying to use this date with the angular material datepicker which uses MatNativeDateModule...  When I try to bind this date to a date picker I get an error message saying the date needs to be in iso format.  i've tried toIsoString but that didn't seem to help.  Any idea how I can go about converting the C#/asp.net date to a format which is human readable and compatable with the angular2-material datepicker?

```
my stringToDate pipe:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'stringToDate'
})
export class StringToDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any) {
        return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you try `return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY').toISOString();`

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296117/datepicker-not-displaying-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-angular-4/53296239#53296239), might help you to solve your problem.